# Podman create: Get "https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/": Forbidden

Tags: containers, podman

After an exausted search, and scratching some solutions, still getting same error after to try a simple `podman pod create -n sample`:

```
initializing source docker://k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5: pinging container registry k8s.gcr.io: Get "https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/": Forbidden
Error: repository name must have at least one component
```

it seems to be an issue related to the version, as I updated the system recently. The `podman` was running completely normal since them. However, I have been reported that the version `3.4.4` was running normally in somebody elses machine.

Podman was reinstalled. Containers, image were cleaned. Docker restarted, but so far, error remains.

Docker version:

```
Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
```

Podman version `podman version`:

```
Version:      3.4.4
API Version:  3.4.4
Go Version:   go1.17.3
Built:        Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 1969
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Debug info `podman info --debug`:

```
host:
  arch: amd64
  buildahVersion: 1.23.1
  cgroupControllers:
  - memory
  - pids
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: 'conmon: /usr/bin/conmon'
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.25, commit: unknown'
  cpus: 12
  distribution:
    codename: jammy
    distribution: ubuntu
    version: "22.04"
  eventLogger: journald
  hostname: Lotte
  idMappings:
    gidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
    uidmap:
    - container_id: 0
      host_id: 1000
      size: 1
    - container_id: 1
      host_id: 100000
      size: 65536
  kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 782991360
  memTotal: 33585106944
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: 'crun: /usr/bin/crun'
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 0.17
      commit: 0e9229ae34caaebcb86f1fde18de3acaf18c6d9a
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +YAJL
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    path: /run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: true
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: 'slirp4netns: /usr/bin/slirp4netns'
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.1.8
      commit: unknown
      libslirp: 4.3.1-git
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 3
      libseccomp: 2.4.3
  swapFree: 19971174400
  swapTotal: 19998437376
  uptime: 75h 31m 50.04s (Approximately 3.12 days)
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries: {}
store:
  configFile: /home/rodolfo/.config/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /home/rodolfo/.local/share/containers/storage
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: extfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 0
  runRoot: /run/user/1000/containers
  volumePath: /home/rodolfo/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.4.4
  Built: 0
  BuiltTime: Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 1969
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.17.3
  OsArch: linux/amd64
  Version: 3.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a proxy setup and I did not checked. So, according to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/196166/linux-command-line-to-turn-off-proxy), unset all them was already enough:

```
unset `env | grep proxy`
```